# Are floating point errors deterministic?

Tags: c++, floating-point

One of the big got'chas of floating point numbers is that some of them cannot be exactly represented in binary. This can make them difficult to work with. However what I'm curious about is whether or not subtle or not-so-subtle errors in floating point are deterministic. Can somebody predict them for example? Here's one example of a random number generator that could take advantage of floating point errors:

```
#include <cmath>

float constant = M_PI;
float generate()
{
    static float state = 1;
    state = state * constant;
    return state;
}
```

One would have to know the implementation, the hardware, the compiler settings and so on, which makes it quite difficult to predict what the results would be. Or is my thinking flawed?

Answer (score 3):

Floating point "errors" are deterministic. There is a 1:1 mapping between input and output values for a given operation. Your example will produce the same output sequence every time.

That said, there could be a floating-point implementation or ten out there that will produce different sequences, but this is not something you can consider "random" (i.e. a source of entropy).

Comment: I agree.  Is there anything that isn't deterministic, other than when talking about quantum physics?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but in the same way that undefined behavior is unpredictable, wouldn't floating point errors also be?

Comment: OK, determinism means something else in computer programs.  The entire system is deterministic though, in a philosophical or scientific way.  I keep hearing non-determinism described as not being able to predict the outcome, or running the same program yielding different results, but that's not the meaning of determinism.

Edit: I just wanna add, I always hear that because something isn't predictable that it's non-deterministic, like chaos theory, chaos theory is entirely deterministic, or the butterfly effect.  I think we're thinking different meanings of determinism here.

Comment: @Ritesh Definition I found: "a nondeterministic algorithm is an algorithm that can exhibit different behaviors on different runs, as opposed to a deterministic algorithm."

So you're telling me that the program

srand(time(NULL); cout rand();  

is a non-deterministic program?

If so, when did computer scientists hijack the word determinism?

Comment: @Titone  srand(time(NULL)) is deterministic. and so is your answer for the floating number. I got misled by quantum physics word :).

Comment: @Ritesh Sorry, I don't know much about programming or computers, but it seems to me there's an entirely different meaning of what determinism means in an algorithm or program as opposed to the common term as used in most sciences and philosophy.  When you say that multithreading is non-deterministic, do you mean that you can't tell which threads are going to act on data at which times, and that each time you run them they give different results?

Comment: @Titone Due to race conditions and context switching among thread, You can not predict which thread will modify tdata in what order. (Syncronization is technique to force order of access on data).

Comment: Determinism in computing means that for a given set of initial conditions and inputs, you can *determine* the output with certainty. While floating-pint rounding errors may seem nondeterministic in a general case, because the computing environment executing the code is not defined, they are not *random* because in practice the computing environment is not random. A given system will not randomly change how it rounds floating-point computations; it will only do so if told, and this almost never happens during execution (and even in the rare cases, it does so deterministically).

Answer (score 1):

Every floating point representation defines the composition of a floating point variable (which part is the mantissa, which part is the exponent, which part is the sign, etc) and the behaviour of every operation.

In any implementation you might choose, it is therefore possible to predict the result of every floating point operation, if you know its operand (or operands)   That characteristic is the definition of determinism.

So, yes, floating point operations are deterministic.

Different implementations (compilers, host systems, etc) do support different floating point representations.   So there is some variation of results between implementations.   However, it is still possible to predict the result of any floating point operation, if you know how floating point variables are represented, and how operations work.

The fact not everyone knows enough about floating point types and operations on them does not make them non-deterministic.  Nor does the fact that not everyone can describe the complete set of operations in a complex algorithm. The knowledge is readily available and, with enough effort, understandable well enough so effects of all operations on all possible operands can be reliably predicted before doing the operation.

There are buggy implementations of floating point out there, which do not comply with their own documentation.  For example, look up the pentium FDIV bug - where some early pentium CPUs implemented floating point division incorrectly. Even those turned out to be deterministic, once it was understood what the operations actually do.